# Swapping text for an image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm looking for a way that I can search an entire HTML document for a specific word and then swap each instance of that word with an image.

The problem I have is that I don't know what content is there because it is a dynamic page where the content is edited elsewhere and the site just pulls it in so referencing classes and ids is difficult.

I created a simple example with text that could resemble the content but the problem I have is my script will replace the whole document (I believe because of .html?) and I just want it to replace that specific piece of text.

```
<p>hi</p>
<p>j</p>


var x = $('body:contains("hi")');
        x.html('<img src="/Content/by_car.jpg" />');
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `x.html(x.html().replace('hi', '<img src="/Content/by_car.jpg" />'));`

Comment: You may want to do some regex to make sure that the "hi" you replace is not in a tag. If not you may end up with "<input type="<img src="/content/by_car.jpg" />dden"/> which would not render correctly in most browsers.

Comment: can use .filter; eg: http://jsfiddle.net/tLwcR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the original html like so `x.html(x.html().replace('hi', '<img src="/Content/by_car.jpg" />'));`

Also, this will be bad if, for example you will have `<p class="hiblo">hi</p>`. In this canse it will replace `hi` in `hiblo` and `hi` inside `p` tag thus ruining your markup.

Generally you can use some kind of regex but it's still not recommended to parse html with regex.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the actual swapping images will use very specific codes and not generic words like "hi", I was just trying to give a simple example :-)

Thanks for the solution though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code.

This code also makes sure that script and style tags don't get replaced otherwise page logic will be broken. So it is taken care of as well.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" > </script>
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hi</h1>
    <div>hi</div>

    <input type="button" onclick="return replaceWithImage()" value="replace with image"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function replaceWithImage() {
            var x = $('body').find(':contains("hi")');

            x.each(function(){
                if($(this).prop('tagName') != 'SCRIPT' && $(this).prop('tagName') != 'STYLE')
                    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="/Content/by_car.jpg" />');



            });

            return false;

        }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```